# CSS background image in a div

Tags: css, html, background-image

Background image does not appear inside a div. Why?

```
<div class="zero">
   <div class="one"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one {
   color: blue;
   border: 2px solid;
   background: blue url("http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/3964/longthinkg5fk.png") repeat ;
}
```

Comment: Your `div` has no dimensions, therefore you do not see the background image.

Comment: That worked- thank you. I figured that it would automatically appear. Not the case apparently.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is okay.

You're not setting `.one`'s height, and it's empty.

After you'll give it dimensions, for example `height: 1000px` (the picture's height), you'll see it.

(I'm not mentioning width here because both `div`s shown here are block elements, which are  100% wide by default.

Comment: No need to specify `width` ;)